# Exception en hilos "código de salida 80131506." C#

Tags: c#

Buen día, en mi aplicación me a estado detonando la siguiente excepción:

> Aplicación: Ia.exe
>   Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
>   Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a un error interno en el runtime de .NET en la dirección IP 6D0F1849 (6D040000) con el código de salida 80131506.

Obteniendo el log a bajo nivel encuentro:

> time: 2019.02.06 16:14:48 UTC, processId: 74872, path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   Exception 0xc0000005: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
>
> threadId 0x1b924 - stack: 1E03C000-1E040000, size: 16 kB, CAUSED EXCEPTION
>     0x1E03F0D8 0x74018647 clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x201ee
>     0x1E03F224 0x7400F033 clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x16bda
>     0x1E03F264 0x7400F492 clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x17039
>     0x1E03F2BC 0x7400EA3A clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x165e1
>     0x1E03F2E0 0x73FE8AB0 clr!ClrCreateManagedInstance+0x326f
>     0x1E03F7F0 0x75F37C04 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
>     0x1E03F804 0x7784AD8F ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x8f
>     0x1E03F84C 0x7784AD5A ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a
>   threadId 0x12494 - stack: 0256E000-02570000, size: 8 kB
>     0x0256FCD4 0x7782C33C ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc
>     0x0256FD4C 0x76102C02 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
>     0x0256FD60 0x7046918C oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x34463c
>     0x0256FD80 0x70469371 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x344821
>     0x0256FD94 0x7040DB27 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x2e8fd7
>     0x0256FDBC 0x70369C56 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x245106
>     0x0256FE1C 0x703692E7 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x244797
>     0x0256FE34 0x70368447 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x2438f7
>     0x0256FE68 0x7036A5E1 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x245a91
>     0x0256FEA4 0x70461EBF oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x33d36f
>     0x0256FEB8 0x70634B17 oneagentiis!RegisterModule+0x50ffc7
>     0x0256FEF4 0x75F37C04 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
>     0x0256FF08 0x7784AD8F ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x8f
>     0x0256FF50 0x7784AD5A ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a

Manejos dlls compartidas tanto para un ambiente web y una aplicación, tengo hilos para llamados a WS y modificación a procesos internos.

Tareas para modificación a procesos internos:

```
try
{
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        new TareasParalelo().Actualiza(val);
        Context.Current.Dispose();
    });
    t.Start();
    var t2 = new Task(() =>
    {
        new TareasParalelo()..Actualiza_1(val);
        Context.Current.Dispose();
    });
    t2.Start();
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.log(e.Tostring());
}
```

El llamado al WS es similar pero guardamos en una variable global "Application.Tar_":

```
if (va1)
{
    if (Application.Tar_ != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Tar_.Wait();
            if (Application.Tar_.IsCanceled)
                Application.Tar_.Dispose();
            if (Application.Tar_.IsCompleted)
                Application.Tar_.Dispose();
            if (Application.Tar_.IsFaulted)
                Application.Tar_.Dispose();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((x) =>
            {
                return true;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Log(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    try
    {
        Application.Tar_ = new Task(() =>
        {
            new TareasParalelo().Tar_(val,val,val);
            Context.Current.Dispose();
        });
        Application.Tar_.Start();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        ae.Handle((x) =>
        {
            Console.Log(x.ToString());
            return true;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando en el exception menciona `w3wp.exe` quiere decir que el problema se presenta en el desarrollo web. Lo que no entiendo es porque desde un `thread` accedes al `Context.Current.Dispose();` estas disposando el contexto web?, porque eso es una pesima idea

Comment: ¿Refieres que el caso del w3wp.exe no se debe a los hilos?, Si se disponsa, para terminar la conexión a la base de datos y no dejarla abierta ademas de liberar esos recursos.

Comment: no veo que tiene que ver `Context.Current` con la base de datos. No se crean objeto globales cuando trabajas con `thread` es para problemas de concurrencia

Comment: Ocurre que Context.Curren es proveniente de un framework proprio, el cual libera la conexión, tu recomendación es que no genere el objeto global para la tarea.

Comment: cuando usas thread los objetos globales son lo priemero que debes evitar, salvo que programes muy bien la concurrencia con conceptos como `lock` o similar https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Ok gracias por el dato, voy a leer el articulo, pero me queda la duda en la Aplicación de escritorio también tengo thread con globales y solo se levanta una instancia por usuario presentándose el problema, siendo que no existe concurrencia.

Comment: una aplicación de escritorio se ejecuta una vez, una aplicación web se ejecuta ppr cada usuario que se conecta, no es lo mismo.